# How can I get the OS X version number in a kext?

Tags: macos, kernel, device-driver, kernel-extension

I have a kext that needs to know what version of OS X it is running on. [CocoaDev has an article](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?DeterminingOSVersion) which describes how to get the OS X version info using Gestalt(), but the code requires Cocoa.

Can I call Gestalt() from a kext?
If so, what #include do I use to define it?
If not, are there any other solutions?

---

Background:

I'd like to use the same kexts in on all versions of OS X from 10.4 through 10.7.

BUT: The [kexts call `cdevsw_add`](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-1699.22.73/bsd/kern/bsd_stubs.c), which was changed in Lion in a non-backward-compatible way. Along with (apparently) changes to some kernel programs that call it, the changes mean — per the comment before the routine — that `cdevsw_add` should be called with a different first argument on 10.7 than on OS X 10.0 through 10.6. (-12 on Lion, -1 on earlier versions.)

If the kexts can determine which version of OS X they are running on, it's easy. (If not, it will be a pain to do — maybe a horrible kludge like building two different versions of the kexts and having the kext-loading code pick which one to load.)

Comment: Out of curiosity, what driver are you looking at? I only ask because I'm fixing up a Lion bug in the OSS tuntaposx driver system right now -- that's why I arrived at this question! Thanks...

Comment: PPS: I'd seen the comment in `bsd_stubs.c` about sending `-1` to `cdevsw_add(...)` quite some time ago. It has actually been in the XNU sources for a long time -- for example, here it is in [the 10.6.0 sources](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-1456.1.26/bsd/kern/bsd_stubs.c). And looking at the code, I think -1 should continue to work fine in Lion, even if it is not an ideal value to send...

Comment: Those version ranges look wrong. Maybe you confused `bdev`/`cdev` or `isfree`/`add`? Here's what I got, feel free to check: **[10.0.0](http://opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-123.5/bsd/kern/bsd_stubs.c) - [10.4.11](http://opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-792.25.20/bsd/kern/bsd_stubs.c)**: must strictly pass `-1` to auto insert; anything less aborts. **[10.5.0](http://opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-1228/bsd/kern/bsd_stubs.c) - [10.7.5](http://opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-1699.32.7/bsd/kern/bsd_stubs.c)**: passing `-1` starts searching at `0`, recommended to use `-12`. (...)

Comment: **[10.8.0](http://opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-2050.7.9/bsd/kern/bsd_stubs.c) - [10.11.6](http://opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-3248.60.10/bsd/kern/bsd_stubs.c)**: same as before, but test is moved to `_isfree`, and now recommended to use `-24`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kernel.framework provides <libkern/version.h>. There are declared  some extern variables like version_major, version_minor etc. AFAIK those are exported from the libkern.kpi.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

[You can use `sysctl` to get the kernel version](http://cocoadevcentral.com/articles/000067.php) (scroll down to method 3). It allegedly works when you develop kernel modules.

Here's an example of the method, in case the site ever goes down.

```
#include <sys/param.h>
#include <sys/sysctl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int mib[] = {CTL_KERN, KERN_OSRELEASE};
    size_t len;
    sysctl(mib, sizeof mib / sizeof(int), NULL, &len, NULL, 0);

    char* kernelVersion = malloc(len);
    sysctl(mib, sizeof mib / sizeof(int), kernelVersion, &len, NULL, 0);

    printf("Kernel version is %s\n", kernelVersion);
    free(kernelVersion);
}
```

Of course, you'll need to figure out the kernel versions of Snow Leopard and Lion, but that shouldn't be very hard. (I can testify that the kernel version of the current Lion release is `11.0.0`.)

Comment: Thanks. That seems to work, at least outside of the kext environment. I'll try it in a kext next. I did have to change "sizeof nib" to "sizeof(nib)" but that was easy/obviously just a typo.

Comment: @user532477, I'm glad this is useful to you. However, are you sure parentheses for `sizeof` are required? As far as I know, they are when the argument is a type, but optional when it's a variable.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know they were optional. This worked great in my testing in **C**, but when I put it in the **C++** kext code I had trouble because sysctl(), CTL_KERN, and KERN_OSRELEASE were not defined (even including <sys/sysctl.h>). I changed it to use sysctlbyname("kern.osrelease"...) and that works fine. For future reference: Tiger 10.4.11 is kernel '8.11.0', Leopard 10.5.8 is kernel '9.8.0', Snow Leopard 10.6.8 is kernel '10.8.0', and, as you said, Lion 10.7.0 is kernel '11.0.0'. Thanks again.

Comment: @user532477, if this solved your problem, don't forget to click the check mark left to the answer: it awards reputation to the answerer and tells future visitors with the same question that this worked for you.